# memoir + thumbs: no trim marks

Tags: memoir, cropmarks

When combining the `memoir` class and the `thumbs` package, the trim marks (i.e. crop marks) are no longer displayed.
updated MWE:

```
\documentclass[showtrims,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setpagecc{240mm}{167mm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{10mm}{15mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{22mm}{10mm}{*}
\setheadfoot{2mm}{0mm}
\setheaderspaces{10mm}{*}{1}
\setmarginnotes{0mm}{0mm}{0mm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\checkandfixthelayout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%edge index
\usepackage{thumbs}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{This is a chapter title}
    \addthumb{}{\thechapter}{black}{black!10}
    \Blindtext
\end{document}
```

After applying `pdflatex`, the PDF looks like this:
[image: 1. page]

[image: 2. page]

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: When I `pdflatex` your MWE the trim marks are displayed but no thumb marks. I also tried changing the class from `memoir` to `book` (commenting out `memoir` specific code) but no thumb marks were displayed. I assumed that you wanted bot trim and thumb marks. Please provide an MWE that shows your problem.

Comment: The use of `memoir` is essential for the document I want to typeset. The example code was is that regard minimal, that loading the package `thumbs`suffices to disable the crop marks. I added the code, that actually inserts the chapter edge index and provided the PDF result I get after `pdflatex`.
If I remove `\usepackage{thumbs}` (and `\addthumb{}{\thechapter}{black}{black!10}`) the crop marks are visible.

Comment: As Peter I don't get the images you post using TeXLive 2020.

Comment: Good point. I don't run TeXLive, but I updated my MiKTeX distribution and that did the trick!
Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, my local version of the `memoir` package (and maybe of some dependent packages) wasn't up to date. Running updates in the MiKTeX console fixed it.

Comment: Note, it is a good idea to use @name when your comment is directed to a certain person, then they'll get notified